# Matlab Google Earth Toolbox to export kml files in batch

Tags: google-earth, matlab

I was running a loop to create separate kml files (from hundreds of point data files) using matlab googleearth toolbox's ge_scatter function as follows:

```
files = dir('*.txt');
for k = 1:numel(files)
Data = load(files(k).name);
x = Data(:,1);
y = Data(:,2);
kmlStr = ge_scatter(x,y);
ge_output(files(k).name,[kmlStr])
end
```

Unfortunately, using files(k).name doesn't give an output (with the same name in the text file) because the conventional way is to write:

```
ge_output('filename.kml',[kmlStr])
```

But in this case, the output file is replaced each time the loop runs. Could anyone please tell me how to run the loop so that I get outputs with respective file names?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the file name at the output that you want to use is `myFile`. Here is what you can do:

```
files = dir('*.txt');
for k = 1:numel(files)
    Data = load(files(k).name);
    x = Data(:,1);
    y = Data(:,2);
    kmlStr = ge_scatter(x,y);
    ge_output(['myFile' num2str(k) '.kml'],[kmlStr])
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would rather write: ge_output([files(k).name '.kml'],[kmlStr]) to get the exact file name of the text file.